# Should "Learn More" CTA be used as a link or button?

Tags: buttons, toggle, call-to-action

**Does it make sense to use "Learn More" as a button to expand more contents?**

See example: http://www.starbucksstore.com/coffee/coffee,default,sc.html

Some of my colleagues argue that after you've expanded, the **Learn More** button no longer makes sense.

Comment: Button looks more prominent in a heavy-graphic envinronment. So the chances of been noticed and clicked are increased.

Answer (score 4):

I think ideally what you'd want to do in this particular case is have the text of the button change after the user initially clicks it to something like "***collapse***." You can probably find a more artful label than collapse in this instance but the learn more label is no longer helpful to users after it has been clicked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The example is (Starbucks) isn't all that great:

```
<div id="learnMoreImg" class="learnMoreBtn">&nbsp;</div>
```

It's neither a link nor a button, but a div. And a div sans any real content. So completely in accessible. Seems pretty sloppy of Starbucks (as they tend to be pretty good with their online properties).

That said, from a user-interaction standpoint, links that look like links are typically links--meaning they navigate you to another page. Buttons that look like buttons tend to be a variety of things. Sometimes you're submitting data, sometimes you're linking to a site, sometimes it's triggering a modal, etc.

In this particular example, I think the visual should better reflect what it does...some sort of toggle for an open/close panel interaction. Perhaps a triangle (pointed right for close, down for open) or a karet or perhaps +/- sign, etc.

In terms of the text, you're right 'lean more' doesn't make a whole lot of sense once it's open, but once it opens, the user understands that it's a toggle, so it's still intuitive in terms of interaction design. Personally, I'd choose "More Information" or what have you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `<button>` (even if it doesn't look like one) for accessibility reasons.

As @the-usability-people stated in their answer, *links should only be used for navigation purposes*. Revealing and hiding content is not considered *navigation*. So, unless you would be navigating somewhere, an anchor link (`<a>`) would not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are for actions

Links are for navigation

Answer: it depends on where the CTA points to

Answer (score 0):

I say that in this case, I think it makes more sense as a link.

1. When you click it, more aside-style info is revealed - no real actions on data are applied. It's more of just a navigational feature.
2. I don't think the Learn More is the main CTA of the page. To me the CTA is to click on one of those bags of coffee and make the purchase.
3. With #2 in mind above, I don't think the button deserves as much visual weight as it has in the context of the content it shows on Starbucks' page.

Downside: IMO, I'm not sure that I would even notice the "Learn More" if it was a link (as opposed to a button). That background image it's place upon is a bit distracting.